# Facebook App Events 0.19 not working in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter application where my task is to log user events using facebook app events. I have added the following package to my pubspec.yaml:

`facebook_app_events: ^0.19.0`

In AndroidManifest, I've added the following meta-data:

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="30923553854348406"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken"android:value="8a8cd2c88b64e9sdf959b900cdd3ad9"/>
```

also style.xml added

```
  <string name="facebook_app_id"> 30923553854348406</string>
<string name="facebook_client_token"> 8a8cd2c88b64e9sdf959b900cdd3ad9</string>
```

When I click this button, I get the following error instead of sending the logEvent to fb:

```
E/MethodChannel#flutter.oddbit.id/facebook_app_events( 3913): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#flutter.oddbit.id/facebook_app_events( 3913): kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property appEventsLogger has not been initialized
E/MethodChannel#flutter.oddbit.id/facebook_app_events( 3913):   at id.oddbit.flutter.facebook_app_events.FacebookAppEventsPlugin.handleLogEvent(FacebookAppEventsPlugin.kt:120)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.oddbit.id/facebook_app_events( 3913):   at id.oddbit.flutter.facebook_app_events.FacebookAppEventsPlugin.onMethodCall(FacebookAppEventsPlugin.kt:49)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.oddbit.id/facebook_app_events( 3913):   at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:258)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.oddbit.id/facebook_app_events( 3913):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.oddbit.id/facebook_app_events( 3913):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:322)
E/MethodChannel#flutter.oddbit.id/facebook_app_events( 3913):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
```